# Trying to create a second loop-single.php to display different posts

Tags: php, css, wordpress

- Basic wordpress install, using a child theme.
- Have a regular "blog", and also a "portfolio" post type
- 2 loop files **loop-single.php** for blog, and **loop-portfolio.php** for portfolio
- My portfolio page always shows up as if there is no styling: http://www.longevitygraphics.com/new/portfolio/dog-patch/
- Both "loops" are identical in code (except I removed the "next" and "previous" links in portfolio). So I can tell it's picking up the file as I don't see the next/prev navigation, but I'm not sure why there is seemingly no style to the page.

**I have tried the following three things unsuccessfully:**

---

```
if(is_post_type_archive('portfolio')){
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/loop-portfolio.php');
}else{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/loop-single.php');
}
```

---

```
if(is_post_type_archive('portfolio')){
    include(STYLESHEETPATH . '/loop-portfolio.php');
}else{
    include(STYLESHEETPATH . '/loop-single.php');
}
```

---

```
if(is_post_type_archive('portfolio')){
    include(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/loop-portfolio.php');
}else{
    include(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/loop-single.php');
}
```

---

To clarify, this is my entire loop... I am not missing calls to `get_header()`, or `get_footer()`, but for some reason it's not picking them up:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php
            if(is_post_type_archive('portfolio')){
                include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/loop-portfolio.php');
            }else{
                include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/loop-single.php');
            }
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: your portfolio isn't even loading the header, check that out first. Also, add some text to loop-portfolio.php and you'll be able to tell which template is loading

Comment: add get_header(); in the beginning of the page and get_footer(); at the end of the page

Comment: I have edited my question...I am not missing the header or footer calls. But for some reason the portfolio loop doesn't pick it up, but the regular blog loop does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of trying to direct the script to my loops in single.php, I ended up just making a separate single.php file for my portfolio custom post type.

**Final Result**

- single.php
- single-portfolio.php
- loop-single.php
- loop-portfolio.php

---

**single.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'single' ); ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

---

**single-portfolio.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'portfolio' ); ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To include a loop template you would use [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) function, and you can then specify the new loop type as the second argument. As mentioned you are also missing calls to `get_header()` and `get_footer()` in your archive template.

```
// Show site header
get_header();

echo '<div id="content">';

// choose the type
$loop_type = is_post_type_archive( 'portfolio' )? 'portfolio' : 'single';

// load the template part
get_template_part( 'loop', $loop_type )

echo '</div><!--content end-->';

// Show site footer
get_footer();
```

Comment: I have tried this method as well, and I'm still getting a blank page for my portfolio items. I have a get_header() and get_footer() call.

Comment: It's possible that something is amiss inside `loop-portfolio.php` then, I am using that method on my site just fine.

Comment: loop-portfolio.php has the identical code as loop-single.php, and the single loop worked fine...that's why I was so confused.